# gforge replacement for git

Tags: git, gforge

We have been using gforge server for cvs/svn. Now we are moving to git. Can you suggest a server for git, which can replace gforge. My server-machine is red-hat, so installing Gitorious is not straightforward. We don't want github.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many servers that have git. Github is the most wonderful. If you don't tell us what restriction you have that makes you not want Github, how do we know which one to recommend?

Comment: We don't want to pay for private repo on github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/) is the standard for in-house serving git repositories, but it doesn't replace GForge; however the latter [has a git plugin](http://gforgegroup.wordpress.com/2010/04/15/git-support-in-gforge/) for connection with your git repos.

To have GForge features an alternative is [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) or [ChiliProject](https://www.chiliproject.org/).

Comment: Thanks. We have tried that plugin. It is clumsy and errorprone.

Answer (score 1):

GForge supports Git out of the box.  No need to change anything at all, though, you'll probably want to upgrade to 6.x.

--Tony